# libmqic_r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, python

Tags: python-2.7, ibm-mq, pymqi

I just created a VM vagrant with centos, installed python2.7 and pip using Miniconda, installed pymqi using pip, created a test python file to see if my pymqi installation is correct :

```
import pymqi
print "hello..."
```

but I got this :

```
[vagrant@localhost projects]$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
import pymqi
File "/home/vagrant/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymqi/__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
import pymqe, CMQC, CMQCFC, CMQXC
ImportError: libmqic_r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I looked for that file :

```
[vagrant@localhost projects]$ find /opt/mqm/ -name 'libmqic_r.so'
/opt/mqm/lib/compat/libmqic_r.so
/opt/mqm/lib/libmqic_r.so
/opt/mqm/lib64/compat/libmqic_r.so
/opt/mqm/lib64/libmqic_r.so
```

Thank you, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/mqm/lib64
```

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, using the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is a bad practice. You'd better just create the appropriate symlink to the 64bit version of the shared objects.

For fome reason, when you install the IBM MQSeries Client, only 32bit mq libraries are linked into /usr/lib/:

```
[root@host ~]# ll /usr/lib/libmq*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Jan 25 12:49 /usr/lib/libmqicb_r.so -> /opt/mqm/lib/libmqicb_r.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jan 25 12:49 /usr/lib/libmqicb.so -> /opt/mqm/lib/libmqicb.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jan 25 12:49 /usr/lib/libmqic_r.so -> /opt/mqm/lib/libmqic_r.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Jan 25 12:49 /usr/lib/libmqic.so -> /opt/mqm/lib/libmqic.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jan 25 12:49 /usr/lib/libmqiz_r.so -> /opt/mqm/lib/libmqiz_r.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Jan 25 12:49 /usr/lib/libmqiz.so -> /opt/mqm/lib/libmqiz.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jan 25 12:49 /usr/lib/libmqjx_r.so -> /opt/mqm/lib/libmqjx_r.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Jan 25 12:49 /usr/lib/libmqmcs_r.so -> /opt/mqm/lib/libmqmcs_r.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jan 25 12:49 /usr/lib/libmqmcs.so -> /opt/mqm/lib/libmqmcs.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jan 25 12:49 /usr/lib/libmqmzse.so -> /opt/mqm/lib/libmqmzse.so
```

While 64bit libs are not:

```
[root@host ~]# ll /usr/lib64/libmq*
ls: /usr/lib64/libmq*: No such file or directory
```

You can fix by just executing

```
[root@host ~]# ln -s /opt/mqm/lib64/libmq* /usr/lib64/
```

Comment: Using it in a slightly different context but this did not solve my problem. I had to use the answer above `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/mqm/lib64`

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have installed MQSeriesClient  or else .so files is not in LIB path